# Update list display in Next.js when passing data from children

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

I have a Page component in Next.js that looks somewhat like this:

```javascript
export default function Index({ containers }) {
  const [containerListState, setContainerListState] = useState(containers);

  const updateContainerList = (container) => {
    containers.push(container);
    setContainerListState(containers);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <FormCreateContainer updateContainerList={updateContainerList} />
      <ContainerList containers={containerListState} />
    </>
  );
}
```

FormCreateContainer allows for the creation of a container. When that API call resolves, I call updateContainerList and pass the newly created container to the parent. This works.

However, I also want to pass this container to ContainerList (which is a simple dynamic list using containers.map()) as part of the containers prop. While pushing to containers works as intended, Next does not live-update my list of containers; the newly created container only shows up when I reload the page.

I thought that including useEffect and changing updateContainerList as follows might work, but alas it did not.

```javascript
  const updateContainerList = (container) => {
    containers.push(container);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    setContainerListState(containers);
  }, [containers]);
```

How do I correctly pass data from a child to a parent component, therethrough passing it to a different child component and updating a dynamic list without reloading the page myself?

I really do appreciate any help as I have done extensive research that did not help me achieve my goal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First and foremost, you should never mutate the value of a prop.

I think you should just use setContainerListState to update the data without mutating the prop like this:

```
const updateContainerList = (container) => {
    setContainerListState(containers => [...containers, container]);
};
```

This will re-render your component and all its children automatically.